# MultiValueDictKeyError in django detail view

Tags: python, django

i am making an app in django. this is my index.html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>The index page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Choose the name of student</h1>
    <form action= "{% url 'detail' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
            <select name="namedrop">
                {% for name in student_list %}
                <option>{{name.stuname}}</option>
                {% endfor %}

            </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my studinfo/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from .models import student

urlpatterns= [
    url(r'^$',views.index ,name='index'),
    url(r'^detail/$',views.detail ,name='detail'),

]
```

and this is views.py

```
from .models import student
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    student_list=student.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('studinfo/index.html')
    context= { 'student_list' : student_list, }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))


def detail(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        name=request.GET['namedrop']
        return render(request, 'detail.html', {'name':name})
```

now it is raising an error 
MultiValueDictKeyError at /studinfo/detail/
"'namedrop'"
i have no idea why...let me know if anybody knows it.

Comment: You're expecting GET data in a POST request?

Answer (score 3):

If `request.GET` is a typo and you meant `request.POST['namedrop']`, looks like there are two things you should do.

Try this in your view:

```
name=request.POST.get('namedrop', '')   # give it a default value
```

This will ensure that you won't have any error even if `namedrop` is not sent. And you can provide a default value.

Then, in your index.html, you should give your `option` tags a value:

```
<option value={{name.stuname}}>{{name.stuname}}</option>
```

Without it, nothing will reach your view.

Hope it helps!

Comment: TemplateDoesNotExist at /studinfo/detail/
detail.html
this is the error it throws after doing what you recommended.didn't work..and i am trying to save the data that the select tag passed to detail.html...why should i use post then?

Comment: @Shefali TemplateDoesNotExist means that you don't have your template in the correct folder. You should use POST because you are using `method="post"` in your html.

Comment: TypeError at /studinfo/detail/
'QueryDict' object is not callable   this is the error it is giving after the above is done

Comment: @Shefali looks like you did not post all your code. And your main question has been answered. For further questions, please ask another question

Answer (score 2):

A very simple mistake is that you are trying to get GET request data whereas you are receiving post data.

Change this

```
name=request.GET['namedrop']
```

To this

```
name=request.POST['namedrop']
```

Comment: i am trying to get the data passed by the select tag in index.html and save that in name variable...how do i do that?

Comment: def detail(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        name=request.POST('namedrop')
        return render(request, 'detail.html', {'name':name})                                          did that...didn't work....now it throws the error...TypeError at /studinfo/detail/
'QueryDict' object is not callable

Comment: @Shefali It's not `request.POST('namedrop')` with parens. Either use `request.POST['namedrop']` as in this answer or `request.POST.get('namedrop', '')` as in the other answer.